# ClassCircularityError inside custom SecurityManager

Tags: java, securitymanager

I am writing a SecurityManager and getting ClassCircularityError exceptions while running a unit test. Examining the stacktrace shows it is complaining about some class that is referenced inside my SM.checkPermission method. To guarantee all classes in my SM.checkP are loaded i cheated and call it once before i officially set it as the System SM. This however does not solve the problem. I am utterly confused why the JVM is attempting to load a class again.

Answer (score 0):

It appears i missed pre-loading one class that is referenced inside my SM, thus is it was having trouble loading that class as it needed it to be loaded before it could verify the load attempt. Ouch.